# Form Open & Close Handling

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am calling up a form that I expect to automatically run some code, then close again.  When I call `Close()` on the form after it's successfully ran, while debugging, it kicks me back to the main application where I ran the form and throws the following exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'ShippingLabelPrintApp'.'

Main module:

```
Module Main

    Sub Main()
        'Add save folder if it doesn't exist
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(savePath)) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath)
        End If

        'saveString = getImagePath()

        'Establish whether we are auto or manual packing clamshells.
        'packMode = ???

        'If we are manually packing clamshells, send to the manual pack station shipping printer (ZEBRA)
        'System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(New ShippingLabelPrintApp)
        Dim manualShipForm As New ShippingLabelPrintApp
        manualShipForm.saveString = "\\Warhawk\users\username\Desktop\Label #794661031570.PNG"
        manualShipForm.ShowDialog()

        'If we are auto packing clamshells, send to the auto pack shipping printer (SATO)
        'convertImage(saveString)
        'transmitImage(saveString)

        Environment.Exit(0)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Form:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class ShippingLabelPrintApp
    Public saveString As String

    Public Sub New()
        ' The Windows Forms Designer requires the following call.
        InitializeComponent()
        print()
    End Sub

    ' Specifies what happens when the user clicks the Button.
    Private Sub print()
        Dim margins As New Margins(70, 0, 35, 0)
        Dim paperSize As New PaperSize("Custom Paper Size", 400, 600)
        Try
            printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Manual Ship Printer"
            'Set internally at the printer
            'printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize
            'printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margins
            printDocument.Print()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("An error occurred while printing",
               ex.ToString())
        Finally
            Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' Specifies what happens when the PrintPage event is raised.
    Private Sub printDocument_PrintPage(sender As Object, ev As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles printDocument.PrintPage

        ' Draw a picture.
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(saveString),
           ev.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds)

        ' Indicate that this is the last page to print.
        ev.HasMorePages = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

I've seen answers on this, but not when the form is basically a popup automatically running and closing app.  How am I handling this wrong?

Comment: You open the new form and then exit the application immediately, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, no, the application exits when the form is closed.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The `Show()` method simply opens the form, it does **not** wait for it to close. Consider using `ShowDialog()` instead.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed if I remove `Close()` from the form, and run the application, the application does not exit until I close the form.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed FYI `ShowDialog()` behaves the same way.

Comment: _"Am I missing something?"_ Yes, you are. If the application doesn't exit when you call `Application.Exit`, there must be another reason _which I don't see in your code_. I suspect you have more code in `Sub Main()`. If so, please post that as well as the code in your form (i.e., how you call `print()`). Again, do **Not** use `.Show()` if you want to _guarantee_ that the next line isn't executed until the form is closed.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I'm not saying your wrong.  I'm just passing on what I am experiencing, which you don't seem to believe.  As you suggested, I've switched to .ShowDialog().  What you see above, as far as the main sub is concerned, is everything that's not commented out for testing.  Print is a function within the form basically called on form load.  I'd be happy to post the entire form when I return to my office.

Comment: Assuming that `Sub Main` is your "Startup object", your current code (using `ShowDialog()` and having `print()` called in the form load event) works fine with me. At this point, I don't think I would be able to help you without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I've added the full scripts for those two.

Comment: I've edited your question and removed the irrelevant parts. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you call your `print()` method in the form constructor and not the form `Load` event as you initially stated. What difference does it make? Well, there are two problems with that:

1. You set the value of `saveString` after calling the form constructor (`New ShippingLabelPrintApp`), therefore, the `print()` method gets called without having `saveString` initialized and `ev.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(saveString),..` will fail. However, this has nothing to do with the `ObjectDisposedException` exception.
2. As explained above, your `print()` method gets executed once you create an instance of the form (using `New ShippingLabelPrintApp`). And since the `print()` method closes (i.e., disposes) the form, the `print` method could finish very quickly, calling `Form.Close()`, and causing the form to be disposed even before the `ShowDialog()` (or `Show()`) is called (which is exactly what happens in your case).

To avoid these two problems, you can simply move the code that's in your form constructor to the `Load` event of the form so that it gets executed only when you call `Form.Show` or `Form.ShowDialog`:

```
Private Sub ShippingLabelPrintApp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    print()
End Sub
```

Or you can set the access level of the `print` method to `Public` or `Friend`, and call it directly from the `Sub Main`:

```
Public Class ShippingLabelPrintApp
    Friend Sub print()
        '
        '
    End Sub
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim manualShipForm As New ShippingLabelPrintApp
    manualShipForm.saveString = "Your\Path\To\The\Image\File.png"
    manualShipForm.Show() 'In this case, don't use ShowDialog so that the next line gets
    '                      executed which takes care of the blocking instead of ShowDialog.
    manualShipForm.print()

    'Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

One last thing, you don't really need to call `Application.Exit` since the application will exit automatically once it reaches the end of `Sub Main()`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  You're right.  I didn't even realize I ran print inside of my constructor sub.  I screwed it up when I tried to tie the two applications together.  I was definitely curious why I didn't end up using form_load event but because it was "working" I wasn't looking at it.

Comment: @Jaberwocky, Glad I was able to help. If there's still something not clear, please let me know.

Comment: will do.  Going to test tomorrow when I get back to the office and follow up.  Thanks again.

Comment: Everything works.  Went with your second solution as that's how I would typically prefer to do things.